# how can I remove dashes from my list python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list

I have this list `[('[]',), ("['843997058062483456', '774956001223770122', '645597259458674707']",), ('[]',), ('[]',)]` and I want to turn it to `[[], ['843997058062483456', '774956001223770122', '645597259458674707'], [], []]`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) in a nested list comprehension:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> xs = [('[]',), ("['843997058062483456', '774956001223770122', '645597259458674707']",), ('[]',), ('[]',)]
>>> extracted = [literal_eval(s) for t in xs for s in t]
>>> extracted
[[], ['843997058062483456', '774956001223770122', '645597259458674707'], [], []]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import json
original = [('[]',), ("['843997058062483456', '774956001223770122', '645597259458674707']",), ('[]',), ('[]',)]
def transform(lst):
  return [json.loads(t[0].replace("'", '"')) for t in lst]

print(transform(original))
```